# How I can make a proof to this conjecture if it is possible?

Tags: reference-request, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, conjectures

Is there someone who can show me the way helping me to proof this conjecture. If it's not open, at a least show me links or papers which to be helpful.

Conjecture: Assume $c > 0$ and that an equilibrium point $\bar{z}$ of the 
difference equation:

$$z_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha+z_{n}\beta+z_{n-1}\lambda }{A+Bz_{n}+cz_{n-1}}, 
\ n=0,1,\dots$$

is locally asymptotically stable. My question is:

Show that $\bar{x}$ is a global attractor of all positive solutions of precedent equation.

Note: this conjecture deal with the following simpler system:
$$\begin{cases} x_{n+1}=\dfrac{\alpha_{1}}{y_{n}} \\  y_{n+1}=\dfrac{\alpha_{2}}{z_{n}} \\ z_{n+1}=\dfrac{\alpha_{3+}+\beta_{3}x_{n}+\sigma_{3}y_{n}+\lambda_{3}z_{n}}{A_{3}+B_{3}x_{n}+c_{3}y_{n}+D_{3}z_{n}}{}\end{cases}
\quad n=0,1,\dots,$$
with non-negative parameters and non-negative initial conditions such that the denominators are always positive.

any help is very welcom , thank you for your replies or any comments